# Why is WCF suddenly requiring DataContractAttributes?

Tags: wcf

I built a number of WCF services as part of an application. Until recently, most of the classes that were used as parameters of the many operations in a service **did not** had the DataContract or DataMember attributes applied to them.

Now, I've made a few changes in a row and all of a sudden WCF is complaining that he can't serialize my classes.

**Does anyone knows if any changes in configuration or even in the ServiceContract, OperationContract etc. can cause WCF to become picky about the classes it can serialize?**

I'd rather not need the attributes in those classes (they should be pure C# classes as possible).

Also of note, if I return to a previous version in my source control, WCF goes back to "normal", so I believe that it's not a machine/environment thing.

Comment: As of .NET 3.5 SP1, WCF did away with the requirement to have `[DataMember]` on individual fields to be serialized. But if your class uses a `[DataMember]` somewhere - when you need to have it everywhere. But as far as I know, this behavior hasn't changed through .NET 4.5 (e.g. you should be fine *without* `[DataMember]` if you so choose)

Answer (score 5):

The ability to create WCF Data Contracts without the use of the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes is a feature added to WCF in .NET 3.5 SP1. Since everything works for you when reverting your code to a previous version, I'm assuming you are already using at least that version.

Nevertheless, in order for classes to be serializable by WCF, the class must meet several requirements [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx). The main requirements of the data contract class are:

- It must be public.
- It must have a parameterless constructor.
- It must not have any data members that do not meet all these requirements. If you do have such a member, mark it with `[IgnoreDataMember]` and it will be excluded from WCF serialization.

You can get more information about what fails to serialize by performing the serialization manually using the `DataContractSerializer` class. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx) for more details and code examples. Another method is to mark all members with `[IgnoreDataMember]` and gradually remove the attributes from members until serialization fails, which will tell you which member is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is lenient towards classes that have [serializable] attribute. You don't require [DataContract]. You must have added something that is not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

I know a way to do that. it's not professional but it works for me
I'm also need pure c# classes so I do it in this way.
I convert each parameter of my class to an object then gather them into array of objects and send it to the other side. in the other side I do the reverse operation to get my parameters back. but this operation will reduce the performance i think